# G Suite Directory User creation is failing with the error - "Invalid Input: primary_user_email"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api

**Issue**:

Intermittently new user creation is not working. It is failing with the error - **Invalid Input: primary_user_email**

Account creation is stopping for both the Admin UI and API also

**Is issue Reproducible?**

We have automation in place which hits the G suite directory API for user/group/role - creation/modification/deletion. So when we have frequent and parallel executions of this automation we are seeing this issue. 
Please note when we don't encounter an issue at the user creating the automation runs smoothly and all the scenarios covered in it are executing properly

**Observations**

- We are not seeing this issue consistently
- Mostly after a window of 24 hours, we are able to create a new user once again with Admin UI and API also
- We are not reaching the API quotas which are available from the Google's end for 100 seconds and for 24 hours
- With the API connection, we are having 2 options - Client credentials(with offline refresh token) and service account approach - both of them have the same inconsistent issue

What we are feeling is that there might be some policies or limits for these API which are blocking the user creation. We have checked the docs available but didn't found any related info.

So we will like to know what actually triggering the user creation blockade so we can work accordingly

**References**

- Directory API used for user creation: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
- Google DOC we are following: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users?refresh=1

Thank you !!

Comment: From the details you have mentioned - "when we have frequent and parallel executions of this automation we are seeing this issue" - isn't it possible you end up passing wrong values for the email? As for the quota - you can check this on your GCP project, selecting `Admin SDK` -> `Quotas`. Do you have any error messages there regarding this? @PrafullPol

Comment: **1. About passing wrong values for the email** - we have verified the email addresses which were passed and they are the valid ones. Also as I mentioned through Admin login also we are unable to create users. **2. About the quotas** We are not hitting the quotas[link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits) For quota issues we do have an Exponential Backoff implementation in place

Comment: In this situation, did you also check the quota information by going to the GCP project as well? @PrafullPol

Comment: Yes, we have verified it we are not going beyond the limits. **1. Queries per day, 2. Queries per 100 seconds per user.** We are not even reaching to close to these quotas. @ale13

Comment: what language are you doing this with PHP or JS etc etc. Can you please specify. I have worked with gSuite api and will be help you if more info provided

Comment: Can you also provide a code snippet for this? Also, are you able to replicate this using the [Directory API Users Reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert)? @PrafullPol

Comment: Language: Java. HTTP REST Way to access The API: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Code Snippet - With Java REST calls I am accessing the API. Replication: I know for sure User creation is stopped for a window of 24 hours. Reason: Trying to figure out hopefully this thread. Once user creation blocked it doesn't work either with UI or API. Yes we are using the same API

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using? And did you try the `Reference` for the API - the `Try this!` section - are you able to reproduce it by using it? @PrafullPol

Comment: yes with the 'Try this!' also we are not able to create users. I have also tried with Postman also the same story @ale13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action of creating and deleting users constantly in a short period of time will trigger an internal system flag at Google and the account will be prevented from these actions for a short time-frame(Approximately 24hrs).
Basically this flag detects im-proper use of the API and to protect the infrastructure, user creation is blocked even for valid email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue you are encountering might be related to your **G Suite account**.

Therefore, the best solution in this situation is to contact G Suite Support [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) and choose the most convenient option for you.

**Reference**

- [Contact G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).